# Is the closure of connected set path connected?

Tags: general-topology

If $U$ is a connected open set in $\mathbb R^n$, is $\bar U$ path-connected? (that is, for any two points $x_1,x_2$ in the closure of $U$, can we find a continuous path connecting them?)

Comment: Is $U$ path-connected or just connected?

Comment: @Adina:  For open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, connected implies path connected.

Comment: Oh, right, of course. Sorry!

Comment: I think not necessarily: There is a well known example of a path connected subset of $\Bbb R^2$ called the topologist's sine curve whose closure isn't path connected. You can just thicken the curve (getting thinner as you go along). The resulting subset of $\Bbb R^2$ is obviously an open path connected set, yet its closure ought not to be path connected.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162867/when-is-the-closure-of-a-path-connected-set-also-path-connected

Comment: It is also sufficient to prove that if $x\in\partial U$, then there exist a ball $B_r(x)$ such that $B_r(x)\cap \overline{U}$ is path-connected

Comment: Does anyone knows a large class of open sets where this property is true? For example, I think that if $U$ is convex then its closure is path-connected.

Comment: @Tomás: That is true because the closure of a convex set is convex.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a counterexample, take
$$U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon \lvert y-\sin(x^{-1})\rvert<x\}.$$
Its closure will be
$$\overline U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon \lvert y-\sin(x^{-1})\rvert\le x\}
 \cup\bigl(\{0\}\times[-1,1]\bigr).
$$
No curve from the interior can reach the vertical segment along the $y$ axis.

Comment: I made the answer community wiki because credit really belongs to @Olivier, who put this idea forward in a comment. Feel free to add explanatory detail if you feel it's needed.

Comment: Why $\overline U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon \lvert y-\sin(x^{-1})\rvert\le x\}
 \cup\bigl(\{0\}\times[-1,1]\bigr)$ ? I mean why did you add $\big (\{0\}\times [-1,1]\big )$?

Comment: @Isabella The curve $y=\sin(x^{-1})$ certainly lies within $U$. In fact, I created $U$ by “fattening up” that curve. If you try to draw the curve, you will see that it oscillates wildly between $-1$ and $+1$ as $x\to0$. So the whole line segment $\{0\}\times[-1,1]$ lies within the closure. More formally, if $y\in[-1,1]$ and $x_n=(\arcsin(y)+2\pi n)^{-1}$, then $(x_n,y)$ lies on the curve, and this pair converges to $(0,y)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I get it. Could you please explain your last line? I don't understand  how is it related to the definition of a not path connected set which is: $\exists x,y\in\overline U,\forall f:[0,1]\to\overline U$ continuous, $f(0)\neq x \lor f(1)\neq y$

Comment: @Isabella Imagine a path $(x(t),y(t))$ in $\overline U$ starting at $(0,0)$, say, and ending somewhere in $U$. Consider $t_0=\sup\{t\colon x(t)=0\}$ (inuitively, where the curve leaves the vertical segment). As $t\to t_0$ from above, $x(t)\to0$, buy $y(t)$ cannot have a limit, since the “wiggly” nature of $U$ forces it to oscillate between (approximately) $+1$ and $-1$. It would take up too much space to give all the details here. But note that the parts of $U$ near the $y$ axis become very close to the curve $y=\sin(x^{-1})$.

Comment: @AllanHenriques (is it really over two months since I came here? wow) – the topologists' sin curve is not open. My anser just fattens it up to create an open set.

Answer (score 5):

I fill in the details of Olivier Bégassat's proposal: Let $Y$ be the $y$-axis, and let $X$ be the union of the open vertical segments $L_x$ centered at the points $p_x=\bigl(x,\sin(1/x)\bigr)$ with $x>0$, with length $2x$. Now I invoke the "comb theorem" (patent pending ;-) ): If $W$ is a topological space, and $Z$ (the "shaft")and $Z_i, i\in I$ (the "teeth") are connected (resp., path-connected) subsets of $W$ such that $Z_i\cap Z\ne\emptyset$ for each $i$, then the union $Z\cup\bigl(\cup_i Z_i\bigr)$ is a connected (resp., path-connected) set.

In our case of interest the shaft $Z$ is the graph of the function $y=\sin(1/x)$ for $x>0$, which is path-connected (the image of the path-connected set $(0,\infty)$ via the continuous function $\sin(1/x)\ $), and the teeth are the segments $L_x$, which obviously are path-connected. Therefore $X$ is path-connected.

The mapping $h:(0,\infty)\times(-1,1)\to X$ given by $h(x,t)=\bigl(x,\sin(1/x)+tx\bigr)$ is a homeomorphism, so $X$ is an open set. It remains to show that $\overline X$ is not path-connected. For this, suppose that some continuous path $\gamma:[0,1]\to\overline X$ is such that $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$ and $\gamma(1)=(1/\pi,0)$. Let $$c=\sup\{x\in[0,1]: \gamma(x)\in Y\}\,.$$
Since $Y$ is closed, then we actually have $\gamma(c)\in Y$, and so $\gamma\bigl([c,1]\bigr)\cap Y=\emptyset$.

Let $(x,y)\in\overline X$, with $x>0$. Then some sequence $(x_n,y_n)\in X$ converges to $(x,y)$, and so $y_n=\sin(1/x_n)+t_nx_n$ with $t_n\in(-1,1)$. Taking a subsequence, we can suppose that $t_n\to t\in[-1,1]$, which implies $y=\sin(1/x)+tx$. This shows that the points of $\overline X$ outside $Y$ are in the union, say $T$, of the closed segments $\overline{L_x}$ with $x>0$ (which is visually obvious). In particular we have $\gamma\bigl((c,1]\bigr)\subseteq T$.

Let $\gamma(x)=\bigl(\alpha(x),\beta(x)\bigr)$. If $c<d\leq1$, then $\alpha(d)>0$. Let $k$ be a positive integer such that $s,t<\min\{1/2,\alpha(d)\}$, where

$$s=\frac1{2k\pi+\frac\pi2},\ t=\frac1{2k\pi-\frac\pi2}.$$

Since $\alpha$ is continuous, then some $d^\prime,d^{\prime\prime}\in(c,d)$ satisfy $\alpha(d^\prime)=s$ and $\alpha(d^{\prime\prime})=t$. In this case we have $|\beta(d^\prime)-\sin(1/s)|=|\beta(d^\prime)-1|\leq s\leq1/2$, and so $\beta(d^\prime)\geq1/2$. Similarly we have $|\beta(d^{\prime\prime})-\sin(1/t)|=|\beta(d^{\prime\prime})+1|\leq t\leq1/2$, which implies $\beta(d^{\prime\prime})\leq-1/2$. Since $\beta$ is continuous, then $\beta(d^{\prime\prime\prime})=1/2$ for some $d^{\prime\prime\prime}$ between $d^\prime$ and $d^{\prime\prime}$.

Consequently, as $d$ goes to $c$, the points $\gamma(d^{\prime\prime\prime})$ converge to $(0,1/2)$. Therefore $(0,1/2)\in\overline{\gamma\bigl([c,1]\bigr)}$, which is absurd because $\gamma\bigl([c,1]\bigr)$ is compact, hence closed, and we already see that $\gamma\bigl([c,1]\bigr)\cap Y=\emptyset$. This contradiction shows that $\overline X$ is not path-connected.