# Uniform convergence of $C^1$ functions up to the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

In Section 1.4 of the book "Partial Differential Equations in Action: From Modelling to Theory" by Sandro Salsa, I encountered the following proposition (rephrased):

> Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, open, connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> Consider a sequence of functions $u_m \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ (the
> notation here means $u_m$ has continuous partials that can be extended
> continuously up to $\partial \Omega$). If $u_m(x_0)$ converges at some
> $x_0\in \Omega$, and $\nabla u_m$ converges uniformly to some $F \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$
> , then $u_m$ converges uniformly to some $u \in C^1(\Omega)$
> , with $\nabla u = F$.

My attempt at proof: The uniform convergence of $\nabla u_m$ implies uniform boundedness of $\nabla u_m$. This would allow proving the **equicontinuity** of $u_m$ (which is both necessary and sufficient for establishing the result) by computing a line integral, IF the domain $\Omega$ has a nice shape, e.g. convex. For general domain $\Omega$, one could still manage to prove the equicontinuity for some $\epsilon$ distance away from the boundary, by covering with small balls, but it doesn't seem possible to extend it all the way to the boundary. For example, consider [the domain in this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286896/is-the-closure-of-path-connected-set-path-connected).

Question: how does one prove this proposition in general? (Or does it even hold in general?)

Answer (score 1):

A bounded, connected, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is path-connected.

To prove it, given any point $x \in \Omega$, consider all points that are path-reachable from $x$, and show that the set of all such points, say $R_x$, is nonempty, open, and closed.

Proofs of each part:

- Nonempty: $x \in R_x$
- Open: given a path from $x$ to $y$, one can draw an open ball $B_y$ centered at $y$, then for any $z \in B_y$, extend the path from $x$ to $y$ by a line segment from $y$ to $z$ to produce a path from $x$ to $z$.
- Closed: show the complement is open. For any $y \in R_x^c$, draw an open ball $B_y$ centered at $y$. Let $z \in B_y$. Suppose there was a path from $x$ to $z$; then one could extend the path from $x$ to $z$ by a line segment from $z$ to $y$ in order to produce a path from $x$ to $y$, but this is impossible by assumption. So $R_x^c$ is open and thus $R_x$ is closed.

Hence for every $x$, $R_x=\Omega$ which is almost sufficient to prove your claim. (The issue is that for your application, you need some control on the lengths of paths.)

Comment: "The issue is that for your application, you need some control on the lengths of paths." - Indeed, that's the block I hit, since there may not be an upper bound for the path lengths, for example if you take a topologist's sine curve and "thicken" it into a bounded, open, connected set, as described in the [answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286896/is-the-closure-of-path-connected-set-path-connected).