# Connecting two points on the boundary of an open, connected and bounded set $Q\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with a path $\gamma\subset \overline{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Let $Q$ be an open connected and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it true that for any two points $x,y\in \partial Q$, there is a path $\gamma \subset \overline{Q}$ which connects $x$ and $y$? I know that $\overline{Q}$ is connected and $Q$ is path-connected, but I still wasn't able to answer my question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286896/is-the-closure-of-path-connected-set-path-connected Does this solve your question?@Mandelbrot

Comment: Thank you, but I already saw this thread. I was hoping to get a positive answer since I only want to connect two points on the boundary and not arbitrary pairs of points. Also  $\gamma$ isn't necesarrily going through any interior points.

Comment: Just take the given example and consider one boundary point on the vertical segment and one boundary point which is not.