# Sets that are also path connected when $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $

Tags: general-topology

Definition for path connected:
A topological space $X$ is path connected if for every $x, y \in X$ there is a path in $X$ from $x$ to $y$. A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is path connected in $X$ if $A$ is path connected in the subspace topology that $A$ inherits from $X$.

Now, Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology and define two sets $A$ and $B$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as:

$A \subset  \mathbb{R}^2$ given as $A = \{(x,y) \ s.t.\  –1 < x < 1\  and\  –3 < y < x\}$
$B \subset  \mathbb{R}^2$ given as $B = \{(x,y) \ s.t.\  –1 < x < 1\ and\ x < y < 5\}$.
Both A and B are path connected.

I've been reading some other Questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162867/when-is-the-closure-of-a-path-connected-set-also-path-connected), and here's a few examples of sets that is also path connected:
$A \cup cl(B)$, $cl(A) \cup cl(B)$, and $A \cup B$.

Are these correct? Thanks.

Comment: Note, per comments on the Accepted Answer that $A\cup B$ is not path connected (not even connected).

Comment: $A , B, A\cup \overline B,$ and $\overline A \cup \overline B=\overline {A\cup B}$ are convex sets and are therefore path-connected.  $A\cup B$ is not connected because $A, B$ are open,not empty, and disjoint in the space $A\cup B$ and their union is the whole space ($A\cup B$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are fine because $A$ and $B$ are well behaved subspaces. But do not get too comfortable with assuming that [the closure of a path connected space is again path connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286896/is-the-closure-of-path-connected-set-path-connected).

Comment: Nor should we expect the union of two path connected sets to be path connected!  In fact here $A\cup B $ is not connected.

Comment: Indeed, this is true especially if the two path connected sets are disjoint and open :).

Comment: $A\cup B$ is not connected. The OP says it is path-connected.